# Saving data from frontend into the database

Tags: wordpress

I am in the middle of creating a plugin. The plugin shows a from on the frontend to the end user. I want the data the user enters to be saved into the database. So I created a custom post type.

So now what I am looking for is how can I save data entered into the form as a record in the new custom form type? At which out of the box functions / hooks should I look?

Can anyone give me some direction to a good example?

Thanks.

Comment: Once the form is submitted, you'll have the necessary data to create the Post. Check [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) on how to create a Post using code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [wp_insert_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post). In your plugin, you'll just want to add it to your form processing. An example:

```
$post = array(
    'post_name'      => 'some-slug',
    'post_title'     => 'Some Title',
    'post_status'    => 'draft',
    'post_type'      => 'custom_post_type'
);
wp_insert_post( $post );
```